# How to achieve i18n/L10n in a backbone.js application?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, localization, internationalization

I am writing a backbone application.
I am writing a template and all the names in template have been given directly.
I want to achieve internationalization , where i should be able to set my preferred locale at start of application and the names should change accordingly.
I dont know how to achieve this.
Any direction in the way ? 
Thanks for help..

Comment: You can try out http://l10ns.org. It gives you a simple getter so you can pass it in to your templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to translate strings I would recommend [l10n](https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/). After a simple setup you can do this:

Include translation strings:

```
{
    "en": {
        "%title.main": "Main Page"
    },
    "de": {
        "%title.main": "Mein Parge"
    }
}
```

Then in your render functions, something like:

```
this.$el.find(".title").html( l('%title.main') );
```